# GROUP_CONCAT returns a row of NULLs if one field is NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select fields from different tables and grouping the rows using GROUP_CONCAT(). However, if one of the fields in the GROUP_CONCAT() returns NULL the entire row selected will be NULLs.

The fields in 'achievement' and 'social' are allowed to be empty. There can be multiple rows of achievement and social per profile.

I have tried changing the query using COALESCE without any success:

```
  SELECT p.UserId, p.Username, p.TextInfo,   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(COALESCE(a.Rank,''), '#', COALESCE(a.Tourney,''))) AS achievements,    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(COALESCE(s.platform,''),'#', COALESCE(s.URL,''))) AS socials   from profile p   INNER JOIN achievement a ON p.UserId = a.UserId   INNER JOIN social s ON p.UserId = s.UserId   WHERE p.Username LIKE '%uagib%'
```

Expected result:

```
<UserId> | <Username> | <TextInfo> | (multiple) <Rank>#<Tourney> | (multiple) <Platform>#<URL> |
```

Comment: share sample data and expected output

Comment: It should not return null. Remove the group concat and post the result of select query including those 4 columns.

Comment: @SalmanA I removed the group_concat and it now returns all empty fields. Same when I try group by

Comment: We really need a short sample of data if you want us to help you more than that. Your query should not return empty fields, there might be an issue with your query and your data but without data we can't find what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend subqueries for this:

```
SELECT p.UserId, p.Username, p.TextInfo, 
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(a.Rank, ''), '#', COALESCE(a.Tourney, ''))
        FROM achievement a 
        WHERE p.UserId = a.UserId
       ) as achievements,
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(s.platform, ''), '#', COALESCE(s.URL, ''))
        FROM social s 
        WHERE p.UserId = s.UserId 
       ) as socials   
FROM profile p  
WHERE p.Username LIKE '%uagib%';
```

Notes:

- This will retrieve users even when they are missing attributes and/or socials.
- The `DISTINCT` is probably not necessary, because you have no partial Cartesian product from joining along two independent dimensions.
- `CONCAT()` is unnecessary.  `GROUP_CONCAT()` accepts multiple arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Group by clause is missing

```
SELECT p.UserId, p.Username, p.TextInfo,   
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(COALESCE(a.Rank,''), '#', COALESCE(a.Tourney,''))) AS achievements,    
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(COALESCE(s.platform,''),'#', COALESCE(s.URL,''))) AS socials   
from profile p INNER JOIN achievement a ON p.UserId = a.UserId   
INNER JOIN social s ON p.UserId = s.UserId   
WHERE p.Username LIKE '%uagib%'
group by p.UserId, p.Username, p.TextInfo
```

Comment: This returns a row with empty fields